# Log Javascript execution output inside Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

So basically I have a large amount of `javascript` source code and will need to be executed via both `Chrome` and `Firefox`. **More importantly, I will need to log the execution outputs for each piece of js code.** Hence, I will need to execute them through the command line.

I tried to compile the `v8` engine of `Chrome` but the process is just broken on my Linux machine for no reason. Also, this approach may not be desired since I have no idea where to find the standalone js engine for `firefox`.

So I am thinking to use a simple `html` file to embed each piece of my js code, and then let both internet browsers to load the html page and execute the js code from there. However, one question is that how can I "log" the execution output? For instance when executing the following command, it simply pops out a web page, and frozen there. I can see my desired output shown in the web page, but don't know how to "log" the output in a file.

```
firefox ./hello.html
```

Could anyone shed some lights on this? Thank you.

Comment: You write that "when executing the following command, it simply pops out a web page". Which command are you executing?

Comment: What is your use case for needing to do  this and can you provide some examples?

Comment: @dybzon Sorry I have updated the question

Comment: Why can't you do what you need within a testing framework? Still not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish here

Comment: But why not run in in a browser? You can use node if you want to run just a JS engine without a browser.

Comment: Unless your code is set up to do this logging then none of this makes sense. Have you tried using front end framework like mocha, karma etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, writing to local files is generally prohibited by the browsers, so in order to redirect the javascript console output to a file you would need to change the environment in some way - fiddle with the browser source code, write a clever add-on or something like that. What happens in the browser, stays in the browser.

That said, you can achieve what (I think) you want by using a browser automation tool like [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). There are also a plethora of testing tools that utilise selenium and the likes.